# How to Select all record when using Union on EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am trying to summarize all the transaction from different table. When I use Union between all table results, it is adding distinct on my query and my transaction summary doesnt show all details.

```
var InTemp =    from a in db.InDetail
                select new Models.TransactionList
                {
                    InOutType = "In",
                    OrderDate = a.OrderDate,
                    Total = a.Total,
                    Operator = a.User,
                    OperationDateTime = a.DateTime
                };
var OutTemp = from a in db.OutDetail
                select new Models.TransactionList
                {
                    InOutType = "Out",
                    OrderDate = a.OrderDate,
                    Total = a.Total,
                    Operator = a.User,
                    OperationDateTime = a.DateTime
                };    
var ReleaseTemp = from a in db.ReleaseDetail
                    select new Models.TransactionList
                    {
                        InOutType = "Release",
                        OrderDate = a.OrderDate,
                        Total = a.Total,
                        Operator = a.User,
                        OperationDateTime = a.DateTime
                    };                        
var query = InTemp.Union(OutTemp).Union(ReleaseTemp);
```

The above code while adding Union, EF adds Distinct, and result shows only unique records, Instead I need all records based on my selection. Thanks

Comment: From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.union?view=netframework-4.7.2): "Produces the **set** union of two sequences ..."

Comment: @dcg Thanks for useful document. I checked it and at the end it says, Concat method returns all elements wheres union return only unique.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Concat()` instead of `Union()`:

```
var query = InTemp.Concat(OutTemp).Concat(ReleaseTemp);
```

`Union()` acts just the same as Sql `union` and returns a distinct result, and `Concat()` does the same as Sql `Union all`.

[Live Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/WbNwSR)

Comment: That was quick answer and hats off to you. I have tested and getting as I expected. Thanks

Comment: @Mdyahiya you are welcome. you can also check the live demo I just added.

Comment: I am looking at it now. Thanks @Ashkan